# PyQt5 render with QWebEngineView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I want render the webpage to an image offscreen, however when I use following code, the output image is blank, I can't solve the problem

```
class PageShotter(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,url,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.url = url
    def shot(self):
        self.webview = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        self.webview.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.url))
        webpage = self.webview.page()
        self.webview.setVisible(True)
        self.webview.loadFinished.connect(self.save)
    def save(self,finished):
        if finished:
            size = self.webview.contentsRect()
            print(u"width：%d，hight：%d" % (size.width(), size.height()))            
            img = QtGui.QImage(size.width(), size.height(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(img)            
            self.webview.render(painter,QtCore.QPoint())
            painter.end()
            filename = 'page.png'
            if img.save(filename):
                filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
                print(u"success：%s" % filepath)
            else:
                print(u"fail")
        else:
            print("Error")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    shotter = PageShotter(web_site.base_url)
    shotter.shot()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the `ScreenCaptureEnabled` attribute, for this you must first enable the `PluginsEnabled` attribute. In addition, the content is rendered after using show, but as you do not want to show the widget, we enable the `WA_DontShowOnScreen` attribute.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class PageShotter(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, url, parent=None):
        super(PageShotter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.save)
        self.url = url
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DontShowOnScreen, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.show()
        settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()
        for attr in (QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, 
                     QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.ScreenCaptureEnabled,):
            settings.setAttribute(attr, True)

    def shot(self):
        if self.size().isNull():
            self.resize(640, 480)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.url))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def save(self, finished):
        if finished:
            size = self.contentsRect()
            print(u"width：%d，hight：%d" % (size.width(), size.height()))
            img = QtGui.QImage(size.width(), size.height(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(img)
            self.render(painter)
            painter.end()
            filename = 'page.png'
            if img.save(filename):
                filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
                print(u"success：%s" % filepath)
            else:
                print(u"fail")
        else:
            print("Error")
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    shotter = PageShotter(r'C:\Output.html')
    shotter.shot()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I know that this is an old question but I will give it a try: This solution works absolutely fine for "real" webpages but if I use local files (and load them with QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.url)) the result is always a blank page. It seems as if the signal loadFinished is raised to early.

Comment: @JoergVanAken what is `self.url`? and show your HTML for testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I should be more precise. `self.url` is something like `r'\C:\Output.html`. The page is rendered correct if I comment out `self.close`. I'm able to produce a png-File if I call the `save` method in `closeEvent` and close the window by hand. But the "automatic" way does not work.

Comment: @JoergVanAken try again

Comment: I'm very sorry, but page.png is still a blank page.

Comment: @JoergVanAken well I have tested it and it works correctly so it is probably a bug of the version of PyQt5 that you use or of the platform where you run it

Comment: Thanks again. I started with a new environment but it still fails. Which version of pyqt do you use?

Comment: @JoergVanAken I am using PyQt5 5.11.3 on Linux