# PySide6 WebEngine Headless Mode

Tags: python, headless, pyside6

I have this code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("YouTube Viewer")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)

        # Load YouTube
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjkrrmBnpGE"))

        # Wait for the page to load
        self.webview.loadFinished.connect(self.page_loaded)

    def page_loaded(self):
        # Create a timer for the delay
        timer = QTimer()
        timer.setSingleShot(True)

        # Function to execute after the delay
        def click_owner_channel():
            # Execute JavaScript to click the owner channel button using XPath
            self.webview.page().runJavaScript(
                'document.evaluate("/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ytd-watch-metadata/div/div[2]/div[1]/ytd-video-owner-renderer/div[1]/ytd-channel-name/div/div/yt-formatted-string/a", ' +
                'document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();'
            )
            pixmap = self.webview.grab()
            pixmap.save("screenshot.png")

            # Close the window after clicking
            timer.singleShot(5000, self.close)

        # Start the timer for the delay
        timer.singleShot(10000, click_owner_channel)

def main():
    # Create a PySide6 application
    app = QApplication([])

    # Create and show the main window
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    # Run the application event loop
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is working perfectly fine, but as soon as i try to hide the window using main_window.hide() or commenting out the main_window.show() the script isn't working anymore. I also get a blank / white screenshot. Am I wasting my time with this? Is there really a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

I tried:
main_window.hide()
commenting out the main_window.show()

Comment: Please avoid asking the [same identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77975043/2001654), instead answer to what's being asked to you. Does it work if you manually minimize the window (or minimize it with a relatively small `QTimer.singleshot()` ensuring it's been shown even if for a small amount of time)? A possible cause is that the web view (and, thus, the page) needs a proper resize event in order to be able to grab the contents.

Comment: it's actually not working, but i managed to find an workaround

    main_window.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool)
    main_window.show()
    main_window.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
    main_window.move(-4000, -4000)

Comment: That may work, but it's still a bit of a hack (that may not work fine on all platforms, as some window managers prevent showing objects outside of the screen geometry). See if this question may work for you: [PyQt5 render with QWebEngineView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47344947)